# Odd behavior when running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, captcha, bundler

I have a project where I used to have simple_captcha gem but no more. All traces removed. I even cleaned the directory and added a new project, even though the bundler installs all gems into a local path called simple_captcha. I have also uninstalled the gem from the system.

Anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that one of your other gems depends on simple_captcha.

Look into `Gemfile.lock`, there you can see which gem requires simple_captcha.